# Is safe to open a transaction with raw SQL in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

With **default settings** in Django (version 3.1) is safe to do:

```py
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("BEGIN")
    
# Some SQL operations

commit_or_rollback = "COMMIT" if success else "ROLLBACK"
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(commit_or_rollback)
```

Or must I set autocommit to `False` with [set_autocommit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.set_autocommit) method before, as Django's autocommit closes transactions? Or autocommit is isolated and there will be no problem with my code?

In case you're asking why I'm using raw SQL for transactions: I've tried using transactions manually as [docs indicates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/transactions/#transactions) but it had some issues with multi-process enviroment, so I had to implement with raw queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've been reading more, testing in my project and seing the queries executed by Django in the database logs. It seems to be safe to use transactions with raw SQL as autocommit begins a new one with any operation and doesn't interferes with transactions opened by others connections